# How to extract these data items from JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file and I would like to get 'id' value and 'key' value for each champion:

Here example with 2 champions of my `champion.json` file, but if I have 100 champions how can I do that?

```jdon
{
    "type": "champion",
    "format": "standAloneComplex",
    "version": "9.23.1",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "version": "9.23.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade"
        },
        "Ahri": {
            "version": "9.23.1",
            "id": "Ahri",
            "key": "103",
            "name": "Ahri",
            "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox"
        }
    }
}
```

My python file :

```
import json

all_data = open('champion.json',  encoding="utf8")
data_champ = json.load(all_data)

for element in data_champ['data']:
    print(data_champ[element]["key"])
    print(data_champ[element]['id'])
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: I have always the same error :  `print(data_champ[element]["key"])
KeyError: 'Aatrox'`

Comment: what happens if you print 'element' and comment out the two existing print statements?

Comment: As to why you are getting that error, `data_champ` does not have a key of 'Aatrox'. However, `data_champ['data']` does, so if you had used `data_champ['data'][element]["key"]` it should have worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the structure of the JSON data in your question, the value associated with the `data` key is a dictionary-of-dictionaries, so you would need to access the value of each one of them like this:

```
import json

with open('champion.json',  encoding="utf8") as all_data:
    data_champ = json.load(all_data)

for value in data_champ['data'].values():
    print(value["key"])
    print(value['id'])
```

Output:

```
266
Aatrox
103
Ahri
```

I also changed the file handling to ensure it gets closed properly by using a `with` statement.